# How i make my javascript function wait to WebSql transactions to finish before continuing

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I made a validate function to see if the value was in the database table. The function always returns true though, even if the value exists in the table. I also tried to return false by just changing a variable value, but that doesn't wait for it so the function returns immediately to the "if" and then `alert("Not in use")`

```js
function Rval(Username,Displayname,Email){

    db.transaction(function (tx) { 
        tx.executeSql("SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE UserName='" + Username.value + "'", [], function (tx, results) { 
            if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                return false
            }
        }, null);
        tx.executeSql("SELECT Email FROM Users WHERE Email='" + Email.value + "'", [], function (tx, results) {  
            if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                return false
            }
        }, null);
        tx.executeSql("SELECT DisplayName FROM Users WHERE DisplayName='" + Displayname.value + "'", [], function (tx, results) {  
            if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                return false
            }
        }, null);
    });
}



if (Rval(Username,Displayname,Email))
{
    alert("Not in use")
}
else
{
    alert("In use")
}
```

Comment: Does `db.transaction` use a promise or a callback to signal it's done? Also, never use `alert`: change your code right now an replace any `alert` with `console.log` instead, and get in the habit of looking at your dev tools console instead. The sooner you stop using alert, the sooner you won't be blocking the JS thread and literally everything that the page you're looking at is trying to do. It's a legacy function that's not meant to be used in modern JS, and no sane modern tutorial will teach you to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```
const userQ = ({field, value, tx}) => 
    new Promise((resolve) => 
        tx.executeSql(`SELECT ${field} FROM Users WHERE ${field}='${value}'`, [], (tx,results) => resolve(!results.rows.length), null))

const getTx = (db) => new Promise((resolve) => db.transaction((tx) => resolve(tx)))

async function inUse(userName, displayName, email) {
    const tx = await getTx(db)
    const [a,b,c] = await Promise.all([
        userQ({field:'UserName', value:userName, tx}),
        userQ({field:'DisplayName', value:displayName, tx}),
        userQ({field:'Email', value:email, tx})
    ])
    return a && b && c
}

inUse(username, displayname, email).then((result) => {
    if (result) {
        alert("Not in use")
    } else {
        alert("In use")
    }
})
```

Comment: First of all thank you, It worked for me, But i had to change the line "if (inUse(username, displayname, email))" to "if (result), I'd just like to know if it's okay to do it like that?

And it's look like i need to learn what is promise,await and async

Answer (score 0):

You can say that your function will return a Promise

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
tx.executeSql("SELECT UserName FROM Users WHERE UserName=?", Username.value, (tx, results) => {
  if(results.rows.length > 0 {
  return resolve(false)
  //or return reject(new Error(error)) for errors
 }
}
```